# discord.Guild.get_member() No value for argument 'self' in unbound method call discord.py

Tags: python, discord, ibm-cloud, discord.py

I'm creating a discord reaction bot which assigns members roles depending on which reaction emoji they use.

I've found `discord.utils.find` works as expected when running the app locally, but doesn't find a member when the app is hosted on Heroku or ibmcloud.

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
     #...
     #...
     #...
        # payload.member is not available for REACTION_REMOVE event type
        member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
       
        member2id = int(payload.user_id)
        GetMember = discord.Guild.get_member()
        RoleLoser = GetMember(member2id)
```

To get around this I'm trying to search the member list for a given guild and return a member using their member id. But running the above prompts the following with reference to this line `GetMember = discord.Guild.get_member()`

```
No value for argument 'self' in unbound method call
No value for argument 'user_id' in unbound method call
```

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: When working with any `on_raw` event, you're only able to access the id for some objects eg. Guild, in your case you should be first getting the guild by ID and then passing it to `find`. So `guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)` (assuming client is commands.Bot(). Thus you should calling `.get_member` on the `guild` object you fetched by their `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InsertCheesyLine is correct. Here is the working code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    # channel and message IDs should be integer:
    if payload.channel_id == 700895165665247325 and payload.message_id == 757114312413151272:
        if str(payload.emoji) == "<:Apex:745425965764575312>":
            guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
            member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='Apex')
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)
            print(f"Assigned {member} {role}.")
```

I've added a print statement that is sent to the console when the user is assigned a role. Simply replace the id's and role name and you're all set.
Refer to where I asked this question and got help solving it (along with the code to remove the role when the reaction is removed): [Assign discord role when user reacts to message in certain channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948611/assign-discord-role-when-user-reacts-to-message-in-certain-channel/63950160?noredirect=1#comment113112899_63950160)